# Min-max selection - what algorithm is that?

Tags: c, algorithm, macros, max, min

I'm trying to understand what is going on in this code -> http://wiki.tiker.net/MedianFilter 
The part that I'm interested in is an algorithm for simultaneous selection of minimal and maximal values from a given list. It (i.e. each of `mnmx*` below) changes the list order so we get a "new" list with a min value on the leftmost place and max value on the rightmost place. Let me quote the relevant part:

```
#define s2(a,b)            { float tmp = a; a = min(a,b); b = max(tmp,b); }
#define mn3(a,b,c)         s2(a,b); s2(a,c);
#define mx3(a,b,c)         s2(b,c); s2(a,c);

#define mnmx3(a,b,c)       mx3(a,b,c); s2(a,b);                               // 3     exchanges
#define mnmx4(a,b,c,d)     s2(a,b); s2(c,d); s2(a,c); s2(b,d);                // 4 exchanges
#define mnmx5(a,b,c,d,e)   s2(a,b); s2(c,d); mn3(a,c,e); mx3(b,d,e);          // 6 exchanges
#define mnmx6(a,b,c,d,e,f) s2(a,d); s2(b,e); s2(c,f); mn3(a,b,c); mx3(d,e,f); // 7 exchanges
```

I can see that it works, but I really don't see how to generalize this for lists of a given length. Is it a special case of some well-known method? Any ideas?

Edit: To reformulate the question: Each `mnmx*` is given by an ordered list of ordered pairs of values ((a,b),(c,d),...(x,z)) such that computing `mnmx*` means computing `s2(a,b)`, `s2(c,d)`,...,`s2(x,z)`. Now, for a given *n*, how to find the shortest `mnmx`, that is, the shortest ordered list of ordered pairs such that computing `s2()` on each of them in the order yields a newly ordered list with min value on the leftmost place and max value on the rightmost place?

Comment: The only one advantage I can think of for Macro in these cases is the type generality (works for all types), but that kinda goes down the drain with `float tmp = a` at the beginning... There are much better ways to achieve the same thing with much more readable code.

Comment: Sorry, which of these puts the smallest element first and the biggest element last? Note that `mn3` and `mx3` don't, although `s2` will. Do you mean that `mn3` puts the smallest value first, and `mx3` puts the biggest value last? That's true.

Comment: Well, I believe that `mnmx3`,..., `mnmx6` do the min-max thing, although I've checked it only for `mnmx6`, to be honest. What I'm looking for is a method to make `mnmxk` for a given _k_.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work for 3,4,5 as well.

Comment: this algorithm is no better than scanning the whole list and keeping track of a min and a max value....it will expand to a series of min, max operations which I guess take advantage of the processor's pipeline but for a large list simply scanning the list is better.

Comment: _Better_ in what way? Nevertheless, it seems interesting how to _expand_ it for a given length.

Comment: So you're only talking about `mnmx*` functions; got it. It might help to clarify that in the question.

Comment: These macros remind me of a line from the Weird Al Yankovic song "Mr. Popeil" that goes "You could even cut a tin can with it. But you wouldn't want to!" `</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question, it is a naive implementation of [Divide and Conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms), where the division is to constant lengths.

It can be extended to a dynamic length by dividing the list dynamically (for example, half of the list), recursively invoking on each half, and then re-combining the lists while modifying the maximum and minimum from the candidates (the first and last element of each sublist returned from the recursive invokation).

Comment: Ok, that is probably close enough. There is one more thing that is interesting to me. Every `mnmx*` is given by an ordered list of ordered pairs of indices i.e. how many times to compute the s2() and on which values. Now, clearly there is, for a given input length, a shortest of such ordered lists (i.e. the shortest of `mnmx`). While doing a _naive divide and conquer_ is ok, I'm not sure if it is equal to _compute s2() the least (for a given length) number of times in such way that yield the desired result_.